# IBM.Data.DB2.Core connection problems

Tags: .net, db2, db2-luw

I keep getting a error when connecting to DB2. But only on the deployed (msi packaged or click-once) app. (And on the same Machine)

Everything works perfectly when running the app from Visual Studio 2017. in either debug or release builds.

I'm using libs from nuget for version 1.3.0.100 on windows 10

I'm also using the free community version of the server, a recent download install on win server 2012 r2.

Any idea whats going on? This obviously inside IBM code...

I know this is not much to go on, but hoping someone has ran into this problem before.

Stack Below:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.Open()
   at FrozenElephant.Symbiotic.DataProviderDB2.DatabaseTypesFactoryDB2.CreateConnection()
   at FormDatabaseConnection.btnTestConnection_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: What does the code in `btnTestConnection_Click()` look like?

Comment: just opens a connection with the connection string, same ones used in Dev/VS. No access to the code now, but can make it available later.

Comment: Looks like [someone else](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014829260) has had this same problem and had it come down to assembly references. Maybe check whether the same version of the client is installed, and perhaps look at whether you're running Copy Local. I'm not familiar with this specific connector, but this might be a clue.

Comment: Here's [another person](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014310931) with a similar report-- the installation seems to have some kind of problem, apparently in locating a factory class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll research this later. FYI, my issue happens all on the same machine. If anyone wants/willing they can try the app and connecting to any DB2/LUW database. APP just loads schema info (poco creation tool). http://www.frozenelephant.com/symbiotic/publish.htm

Comment: Whoops, just crossed posts with you. I'll check the ClickOnce and see if there's anything to add to my answer. I didn't realize it was all on the same machine.

Comment: ok, FYI; the Test Connection button show an Error window which you can copy/paste the stack. Maybe it will work for you. Again the problem is only when connecting to DB2/LUW databases, all other vendors work.

Comment: The windows store build works. https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NN20Q6WFKGS

Comment: I haven't been able to get a working DB2 environment set up yet. But see my comment on the difference between the Windows Store and and ClickOnce deployments below-- that could have something to do with it.

Comment: yeah, took me a while. IBM stuff is really sub standard. I spent a week just getting things working and I had to use Oracle Sql Developer to do most of the work. The IBM client tools are a complete mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the findings above in the form of an answer, since I may not get back to elaborate on my comments for a while.

It appears that this problem is the result not of a code error, but of the disposition of the DB2 connector on the target machine that fails, or perhaps in how the application is deployed. Deciding which is the culprit will need to be done by looking at how the redistributable parts of the connector are deployed.

[One user](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014829260) said that he "was not referencing the assemblies correctly in my application". A few possibilities this might indicate include:

- A different version of the SDK is used for development compared to what is on the target machine
- Perhaps multiple different assemblies of conflicting version or origin have been mixed
- The assemblies may need to be deployed with the application, and not all are. This could be fixed by setting Copy Local = true for the relevant assemblies.
- It might also be that the application is being compiled for a different platform than the client installed on the target machine (say, x64 version x86).

[Another person](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014310931) mentions the same error message arising from a similar, but slightly different, cause. This one says "It seems to be an installation issue. Some files are not found."

In this case, you would probably be looking at reinstalling the client or diagnosing the install in another way. The second link above mentions a tool, **testconn20**, which may be available in the client you have installed. Your connection string might also offer some hints; if there's anything in it which might depend on the specific client you have installed, or its capabilities, that'd be another place to check.

Edit:

Per my comment below, you may be missing some files or folders from the ClickOnce deployment. If you determine that the clidriver folder, which has DB2-related files in it, is necessary for the application to function properly, you should check the build action, copy to output directory, and ClickOnce application files settings. The last one may be key. To check that, go to Publish in the project properties:

[image: Location of ClickOnce application files settings]

Then you may need to check "Show all files" to confirm the status of each file in the deployment:

[image: Application files settings example]

Comment: @Eric-Schneider It looks like in the Windows Store version you have a folder "clidriver" which is not present in the ClickOnce executable install directory. Is it present in your debug or release folders? Is it possible that you are missing it in your deployment?

Comment: looks like that was it, great work dude! now I wonder why such mixed results. I guess the msi project build has a bug?

Comment: To clarify for other devs: It was missing the "clidriver" folder. So seems the MSI project does not find it so I copied the folder into the project folder. the show all files, right click "Include in project"

Comment: The folder is over 69MB ! Can that entire folder really be required?

Comment: I don't know, but I will say I noticed the big difference in download size between the Windows Store app and the ClickOnce-- it was one of the things that pointed to the solution. You'll need to look into that, but happy to hear you have a way forward.

Comment: yes, I have a request out to IBM, but the turnaround seem to be about a WEEK. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=05d08e6b-2727-47c5-80cd-ab8b5ee9adc3

Comment: oops, didn't realize i need to click the bounty! I thought just the check on the answer was enough...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I solved it by putting the directory `clidriver` inside the working directory. Also, I set the following environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/app/deployments/v1.0
export DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH="/opt/app/deployments/v1.0/clidriver"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/app/deployments/v1.0/clidriver/lib"
export PATH=$PATH:"/opt/app/deployments/v1.0/clidriver/bin:/opt/app/deployments/v1.0/clidriver/adm:/opt/app/deployments/v1.0/clidriver/lib"
export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=STAGING
export ASPNETCORE_INSTANCENAME=app01
/opt/app/runtime/aspnetcore-runtime-3.0.0-linux-x64/dotnet /opt/app/deployments/v1.0/Launcher.dll
```