# Using IBM.Data.DB2.Core to connect to DB2 - ERROR when trying to open connection - Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')

Tags: azure, .net-core, db2, azure-functions, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect to DB2 with .Net Core (Using IBM.Data.DB2.Core) as per code below from a .Net Core 3.1 Azure Function but when I run locally I am getting the error below when I hit the connection.Open() :

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.Open()
   at DB2Test.Function1.Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) in C:\Users\cmere\source\repos\DB2Test\DB2Test\Function1.cs:line 46

using IBM.Data.DB2.Core;
        {

```
           DB2ConnectionStringBuilder connStringBld = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder();
           connStringBld.Database = "DBNAME";
           connStringBld.UserID = "USERID";
           connStringBld.Password = "Pa%%w0rd";
           connStringBld.Server = "xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx";
           connStringBld.Authentication = "SERVER";
           connStringBld.ClientApplicationName = "TEST";
           connStringBld.ClientWorkstationName = "TEST";
           connStringBld.DBName = "DBNAME";
           connStringBld.Pooling = true;
           connStringBld.ProgramId = "12345";

           DB2Connection myConn = new 
           DB2Connection(connStringBld.ConnectionString);

           myConn.ClientUser = "AISSRVCDEV";
           myConn.SetConnectionString(myConn);
           myConn.ConnectionString = myConn.ConnectionString;
           myConn.ClientAccountingInformation = "TEST";
           myConn.ClientCorrelationToken = "TEST";
           myConn.ClientProgramName = "TEST";


           try
           {
                myConn.Open();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
            return new ObjectResult(ex.ToString());
           }
           return new OkObjectResult("OK");
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, IBM documentation is non existent!
Thanks in advance.
Dino

Comment: Is connStringBld.ConnectionString properly defined? https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/IBM.Data.DB2/DB2ConnectionStringBuilder/-/php-db2connectionstringbuilder-class-examples.html

Comment: Thanks bestinamir - I've tried again with:     connStringBld.allowDynamicSQL = true;
            connStringBld.Connect_Timeout = 60;
            connStringBld.PersistSecurityInfo = true;  But still same error.

Comment: I'm not a DB2 specialist but I see something strange in the code: myConn.SetConnectionString(myConn); myConn.ConnectionString = myConn.ConnectionString;  I would delete these two lines.

Comment: Issue resolved with the Beta version of the next release of the .Net Core 3.1 nuget.  Unfortunately there is a license cost required too.

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096058/ibm-data-db2-core-connection-problems) helpful to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length') at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.Open(
```

Per this, I assume this is a connection pool related.  Try setting `connStringBld.Pooling` to **false** instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Samuel, I have tried with pooling false too and this unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Alpha or Beta version of the .NET Core 3.1?

This issue has been fixed in the Beta version.

Comment: No, I am not on the Beta version of .Net Core 3.1.  Do you know how I can obtain the Beta code please?